# Java servlet filter - block all requests from client

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-filters

I want to block all requests from client at some point, 
meaning any request that the server receive a filter will not forward it and stop the chain,
So the user will stay on the current page.

how can I achieve that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just either add a return statement to the end of the if

```
if (sn.startsWith("www.")) {
    String url = "http://" + getDefaultDomain() + req.getContextPath() + req.getRequestURI();
    HttpServletResponse resp = (HttpServletResponse) response;
    resp.reset();
    resp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_MOVED_PERMANENTLY);
    resp.setHeader("Location", url);
    return;
}
chain.doFilter(request, response);
```

Comment: thanks for the replay but from reading your code I'm assume you are doing forward to the requested URL.. because url is taken from the request